# Directory permissions within docker container seem to differ between MacOS and Ubuntu

Tags: docker, docker-compose

This docker-compose fragment works fine when the host is MacOS, but fails when the host is Ubuntu:

```
version: '3.3'

services:
  cassandra1:
    image: cassandra:3.5
    container_name: cassandra1
    restart: always
    environment:
      JVM_EXTRA_OPTS: -Dcassandra.config=/home/cassandra/cassandra.yaml
    volumes:
      - ./root/cassandra/keystore:/home/cassandra/conf/.keystore:ro
      - ./root/cassandra/keystore:/home/cassandra/conf/.truststore:ro
      - ./root/cassandra/cassandra.yaml:/home/cassandra/cassandra.yaml:ro
      - ./root/cassandra/cassandra-rackdc.properties:/home/cassandra/cassandra-rackdc.properties:ro
      - ./data/cassandra1/data:/home/cassandra/data
      - ./data/cassandra1/commitlog:/home/cassandra/commitlog
      - ./data/cassandra1/saved_caches:/home/cassandra/saved_caches
      - ./data/cassandra1/hints:/home/cassandra/hints
```

Cassandra complains:

```
cassandra1    | ERROR 04:19:55 Doesn't have write permissions for /home/cassandra/data directory
cassandra1    | ERROR 04:19:55 Insufficient permissions on directory /home/cassandra/data
```

Using docker exec fails to connect, so no luck seeing into the container for diagnosis:

```
>docker exec -it 771 bash
Error response from daemon: Container 
7714bb1959eb814d2fb7479b6f74555d308d2c8951f4ad0f54931ecb23f41893 is restarting, wait until the container is running
```

Any thoughts why there's a permission issue? Any guidance on getting visibility into the container to see what's going on?

Answer (score 1):

Run ps inside the cassandra docker to discover the user ID (UID) of the process:

```
~/tmp $ docker exec -it cassandra1 ps -ef
UID        PID  PPID  C STIME TTY          TIME CMD
cassand+     1     0 20 07:18 ?        00:00:00 /bin/sh /usr/sbin/cassandra -f
root        40     0  0 07:18 pts/0    00:00:00 ps -ef
cassand+    92     1  0 07:18 ?        00:00:00 java -cp /etc/cassandra:/usr/sha
cassand+    93     1  0 07:18 ?        00:00:00 grep -q Error: Exception thrown
```

The cassandra process UID is cassand+

Find the UID inside the docker /etc/passwd

```
~/tmp $ docker exec -it cassandra1 grep cassand /etc/passwd
cassandra:x:999:999::/home/cassandra:/bin/sh
```

The cassandra process inside the docker runs as UID 999

Now we know that any files in the root/data volumes need to be owned by user UID 999 in order to allow the docker to write files to the host's file system.

```
~/tmp $ sudo chown -R 999:999 root data
~/tmp $ sudo chmod -R 755 root data
~/tmp $ ls -la
total 20
drwxrwxr-x  4 ubuntu ubuntu 4096 Dec 24 09:36 .
drwxr-xr-x 84 ubuntu ubuntu 4096 Dec 24 09:36 ..
drwxr-xr-x  3    999    999 4096 Dec 24 09:14 data
-rw-rw-r--  1 ubuntu ubuntu  454 Dec 24 09:36 docker-compose.yml
drwxr-xr-x  2    999    999 4096 Dec 24 09:36 root
~/tmp $
```

Is is possible that on your mac the root and data directories are write enabled by your default user as UID 999 while on your Linux the default user can't write to the root and data directories as user UID 999

Comment: `docker exec` fails on the linux host, but it's probably a safe guess that the container user and group are the same as on the mac host. We're not writing under ./root, it's all used read-only, so there's no issue there. The directory ./data does not exist before running `docker-compose up`, it's created by docker. An interesting difference though - on mac, everything under ./data is my user, on linux they're all owned by root. So, docker's creating them as root.

Comment: There is one major difference between Linux docker and MacOS docker, the docker engine on Linux runs under the Linux OS while in MacOS there is a Linux VM that runs the docker engine. This can account for the difference in how docker works.

Comment: Oh, interesting. I'll have to read more about that. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Here's something that works, though it's not a satisfying answer. If I create the directories before running `docker-compose up`, docker uses what's there.

On a Linux host, docker_dirs.txt:

```
data/cassandra1/commitlog
data/cassandra1/saved_caches
data/cassandra1/data
data/cassandra1/hints
```

Then:

```
cat docker_dirs.txt | xargs mkdir -p
chmod -R a+rw data
```

After this, run `docker-compose up`, docker uses the volumes, and everything works as it would on a Mac host.

Ideally, I'd want identical behavior between the two OSs.